# Who killed Siggy, the daughter of Bjorn Ironside?

Tags: plot-explanation, vikings

In episode 9 of season 4 of *Vikings*, who killed Siggy, the daughter of Bjorn Ironside?

Siggy is neglected and not properly taken care of and later found dead by Sigurd, lying in the mud in a stream below a bridge. What caused her death or who killed her?

Comment: http://vikings.wikia.com/wiki/Siggy_(Bjornsdottir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The girl likely drowned in the river trying to wash herself, as Sigurd (who discovers her later in the water) noticed that she was dirty. I don't think anyone killed her, she just died of neglect. Her mother had abandoned her, her father was off raiding, and her step-grandmother who was supposed to be caring for her was too drunk to notice or care that she was missing.

Comment: Can agree. Thanks. Small correction Porrun (mother) was not dead. She just left Kattegat.

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera Ah, you're right. Considering her state of mind, I had assumed that she had gone off to die alone in the wilderness, but they never do show exactly what becomes of her.